# Word for someone who has others make decisions for them?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

If I want to say

> the root of all his problems was that he was a [insert word/phrase for someone who has others make decisions for them]

What is an idiom, metaphor, or word that I could use?

Comment: Maybe ..."puppet", or  "figurehead"? Please show some research.

Comment: I think we need more context here. There are various reasons why someone would have other people make decisions for them - youth, or infirmity, or willingness to be a figurehead would give rise to very different descriptions.

Comment: This question is severely lacking context.  If you don't edit to explain the situation better the question will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is

> ***a pushover***

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pushover) defines it as

`someone who is easily controlled, offers very little resistance to what someone else wants to do, and backs down easily`

Another [dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pushover) defines it as

`a person who is easily persuaded, influenced, or seduced`

You may also think of expressions like ***man of straw, easy meat*** or ***easy game***.

Answer (score 1):

**Acquiescent**

> Accommodating or permissive in nature
> (of a person) Easily influenced by feelings or emotions
> Failing to act or protest as a result of moral weakness or indolence

Comment: You should include the source of your definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [guardian](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/guardian):

> *Law.* a person who is entrusted by law with the care of the person or
> property, or both, of another, as a minor or someone legally incapable
> of managing his or her own affairs.

And the person who is under care could be a *ward*.